# What error code to send with php if the data was not found in DB?

Tags: php, http

I need to send a http_response_code() with php to an Ajax GET call but I do not know what error code to use if the requested data, for example user id is not in the database. I used 404 but it might be mistaken with file not found. Is there another way to send error code and maybe some additional information?

Comment: You can use any number you like as long as it is properly documented

Comment: If its an ajax call send back JSON, its easy for javascript to process. It can be anything but for example `json_encode(['status' => ['errcode'=> 99, 'errmsg'=>'Woops']]);`

Comment: And if you want to return data `json_encode(['status' => ['errcode'=> 0, 'errmsg'=>''], 'data' =>$dataArray]);`

Comment: I'm oddly fond of [418: I'm a teapot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/418)